# How can I prove that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am asked to prove that

$$P(x) = x^6 + x + 1$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$.

I tried using Eisenstein criteria by a doing a change of variable such as $x = y + a$ but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: You can try to prove irreducibility straight-forward (but I'm not sure if this works or not): supposet that for some $Q, R\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have $P=Q\cdot R$. Then, we will obtain some system for coefficients of $Q$ and $R$ (and they are integers). Moreover, $Q(0)R(0)=1$, $Q(-1)R(-1)=1$ and $Q(1)R(1)=3$, so it can ease your problem.

Comment: I would immediately spot this as remaining irreducible modulo two, so it will have to be irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ as well. Verifying that is easy if you have memorized low degree irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Anyway, both the answers are nice, and I have used that trick on the site enough many times already, so only leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^6+x+1$ has no real roots, so it can't have any factors of odd degree.  The only possibility for factoring is as the product of a quadratic and a quartic.  The quadratic would have to be of the form $x^2 + a x + 1$ or $x^2 + a x - 1$ where $a$ is an integer.
The second form is out because it would have a real root.  The first would have a real root if $|a|\ge 2$.  That leaves only three possibilities, which are easy to check.

Comment: Why the absence of real roots leads to no factors of odd degree?

Comment: @Ralph Because every polynomial of odd degree has at least one real root.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion):

> If there is an integer $b\geq 2$ such that $0 \leq a_k \leq b-1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k b^k$ is a prime, then $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k x^k$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Since $f(x)=x^6+x+1$ has non-negative coefficients, we can try some integers $b$ larger than any of its coefficients, and see if we get $f(b)$ a prime. Already the smallest one $b=2$ gives $f(b)=2^6+2+1=67$ a prime, hence $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.