# Proof verification - Polynomials irreducibility criterions

Tags: solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to check if the theorem proved and its corollaries are correct, and useful as criterions for determining if a polynomial is irreducible or not. Also, I would like to know about their extendability as criterions of irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$, $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$, $\mathbb{R}\left[x\right]$ and $\mathbb{C}\left[x\right]$.

In mathematics, an irreducible polynomial (or prime polynomial) can be defined as a non-constant polynomial that cannot be factored into the product of two non-constant polynomials.

In this context, we can set the following

**Theorem**. *If some univariate polynomial $P_{n}\left(x\right)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x+a_{0}$ is reducible such that $P_{n}\left(x\right)=Q_{k}\left(x\right)R_{j}\left(x\right)$, where $Q_{k}\left(x\right)=b_{k}x^{k}+b_{k-1}x^{k-1}+...+b_{1}x+b_{0}$ and $R_{j}\left(x\right)=c_{j}x^{j}+c_{j-1}x^{j-1}+...+c_{1}x+c_{0}$ are two non constant polynomials, then $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}c_{i}\right)$*

*Proof*. As $P\left(x\right)=Q\left(x\right)R\left(x\right)$, it follows that $P\left(1\right)=Q\left(1\right)R\left(1\right)$. And expanding, we get

$P_{n}\left(1\right)=a_{n}1^{n}+a_{n-1}1^{n-1}+...+a_{1}1+a_{0}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}$

$Q_{k}\left(1\right)=b_{k}1^{k}+b_{k-1}1^{k-1}+...+b_{1}1+b_{0}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_{i}$

$R_{j}\left(1\right)=c_{j}1^{j}+c_{j-1}1^{j-1}+...+c_{1}1+c_{0}=\sum_{i=0}^{j}c_{i}$

Getting the desired result.

**Corollary 1**. As a prime number can only be multiple of $1$ and itself, and there exist no sum of positive integers equal to $1$, it follows directly from the Theorem stated that, if $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}$ is some prime number, then $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z^+}\left[x\right]$.

My guess is that, unfortunately, the criterion set in the corollary is not extendable to $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$, as there do exist sums of positive and negative integers equal to $1$.

However, we could state that

**Corollary 2.** If $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}$ is some prime number, then $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$ only if either $Q_{k}\left(1\right)$, or $R_{j}\left(1\right)$, or both, have at least one negative coefficient. And, as if $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}$ is some prime number, then $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ is primitive, by Gauss Lemma we have that $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$ only if either $Q_{k}\left(1\right)$, or $R_{j}\left(1\right)$, or both, have at least one negative coefficient.

Also, if you do know / think of further corollaries from the theorem stated, it would be great to know about them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A very beautiful result is that if the integer $N=a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_0$ is a prime then the polynomial $a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$ is irreducible. I don't remember where I have read the source.

Comment: @piquito an integer $N=a_{n}a_{n-1}...a_0$ can be some prime number only if the absolute value of every coefficient is equal to $1$ excepting one of them, which is equal to that prime number. If what you say is correct, is a pity that you do not remember the source, a proof of irreducibility of such polynomial would be great to know!

Comment: @JuanMoreno Your statements seem correct to me, just two minor terminology comments: 1) it should be "irreducible **over** $\mathbb{Z}$" or "irreducible **in** $\mathbb{Z}[x]$", 2) term "irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$" is a bit strange because irreducibility is usually done over rings, but $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ is not a ring...

Comment: @Sil thanks for your comments, just fixed the terminology as you indicate in 1). As for your comment in 2), unfortunately I do not know how to express it differently, if you could suggest something more appropriate it would be welcomed. Maybe stating it as "irreducible in polynomials with all their coefficients positive"?

Comment: @JuanMoreno I would keep it as it is, it's just thing to keep in mind... (if it contained 0 I would say it is at least semiring, but with positive coefficients only it's not even that :) )

Comment: @Sil: your artifice is not valid, dear friend, your $2$ is just $2$ and not any operation or algorithm giving $2$ as result. Regards.

Comment: If you have thougt that $121$ is prime then I understand the reason of your reply. But $121$ is not prime.

Comment: What @Piquito is most likely referring to in his first comment is known as [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) and $N=a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_0$ means concatenation of digits (not a product!). Little more precisely, if all coefficients $0 \leq a_i < b$ for some base $b$ and $a_{n}b^{n}+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+...+a_{1}b+a_{0}$ is a prime, then $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x+a_{0}$ is irreducible. As an example, for $b=10$ (decadic) we see $1013$ is a prime and so Cohn's criterion implies that $x^3+x+3$ is irreducible.

Comment: OK, Sil, I delete my comments as you want. The source I read some time ago was not in Wikipedia but the original paper in some journal. Anyway I don't believe you know this Cohn's criterion before. Regards.

Comment: I know it, it's actually quite commonly used even on this site (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701373/how-can-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-mathbb-zx/3701460#3701460), but it can still be useful/interesting to the OP.

Comment: It is really interesting indeed! Helpful discussion, thanks both!

Comment: If you knew it, then why didn't you tell Juan Moreno in his first comment, wanting to find out about the source? I don't believe you, it's my point of view on this. Take it as simple freedom of thought and excuse me then.

Comment: @Piquito I think there is a language problem because you keep misinterpreting what I say and you keep responding with irrelevant stuff. I knew the Cohn's criterion, I did NOT know that you were referring to Cohn's criterion (because you haven't mention anything about concantenation of digits, and what you wrote is in mathematics interpreted as a product, almost everyone will interpret it that way). Why this is so hard to understand?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU